How to get MILLISECOND from Oracle interval value?
How to get MILLISECOND from Oracle interval value?
For instance if the interval value is '+000000000 00:12:59.144721' then the result will be 145

I think you can do only like this one:
WITH t AS (
    SELECT INTERVAL '0 00:12:59.144721' DAY TO SECOND AS intv
    FROM dual)
SELECT 
    1000 * ROUND(
        EXTRACT(SECOND FROM intv) - TRUNC(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM intv)),
    3) AS MILLISECOND 
FROM t;


You can use EXTRACT and take the MODulus:
SELECT ROUND(MOD(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM value), 1) * 1000) AS ms
FROM   table_name;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT INTERVAL '0 00:12:59.144721' DAY TO SECOND FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



MS




145



fiddle
